# localStorage returns null because of parsing

Tags: json, parsing, local-storage, undefined

I know that this question has already been here but these solutions couldn't help me. I might even know what the problem is but I can't figure it out how to work this out.

I am trying to parse some text that I get from my backend and I want to store it in localStorage by using setItem. It works fine. When I load the other page I still have the information. When I try to parse it back and store the value of some keys in a list it doesn't work. I am using a for loop to go through the information but I think the problem is that the loop still recognizes it as a String and loops through every letter instead of every key. So that is why it won't find my given keys. The js code for page 1 where I get the data from the backend looks like this:

```
xhttp.onload = function() {

        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        localStorage.setItem("Json", JSON.stringify(this.responseText)); <-----

        showDataInTable(jsonResponse);

        var label = document.getElementById("labelOfMaxPages");
        label.innerText = "von " + maxPages;
    }
```

On the other js file where I want to collect the data like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Json"));  <----
    console.log("JSON RESP: " + jsonResponse);
    console.log("LENGTH: " + jsonResponse.length);
    var diesel = getListFromJson("diesel", jsonResponse);
    var e5 = getListFromJson("e5", jsonResponse);
    var e10 = getListFromJson("e10", jsonResponse);
    console.log(diesel);
    const chart = document.getElementById("line-chart");
}

function getListFromJson(type, jsonResp) {

    var typeList = [];
    for (index = 0; index <= jsonResp.length - 1; index++) {
        typeList.push(jsonResp[index].type);
    }
    return typeList;
}
```

And this is what I get in the console:

[image]

Thank you already!

Comment: Again I'm sorry if this exact question has already been here. I even tried it with the soloutions I found on sof about storing objects in localstorage with stringify and parse but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Can you post your jsonResponse  object pls?  Just several items for testing

Comment: I have no object for it. I just get the data from the backend and stringify it into the localStorage. After that I parse it back into the var jsonResponse by using var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Json"));.
Do I have to make an object with id,name, brand etc.? I'm sorry I am pretty new to Json and JS.